# Can Chart.js paint stack bar chart border-radius like this?

Tags: highcharts, chart.js

[image]

I'd like to get a chart like this one.

Can someone post some tips?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Chart.js is not the same as Highcharts. Please specify what JS lib are you using? Also, a code sample or a live demo of what you have already tried or have will help.